# Relationship between "see" and "look"

Tags: terminology, semantics, lexical-semantics

I'm interested in how "see" and "look" relate to each other. I think "hear" and "listen" is similar. Is there specific linguistic terminology that describes how the words relate to each other?

To me it seems like English has no word that similar to "look" for "smell" or "feel". Is that true for most/all languages? Are there languages who do something more clever to handle this area?

Comment: For smell there's _sniff_ although that word also carries specific connotations as to the manner and the sound made while doing the action; for feel there's _touch_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*See* and *look* are [***Sense Verbs***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299). They are, in fact, the two distinct English sense verbs for vision.

There are three varieties of English sense verbs, following the pattern of *hear, listen, sound*
(only sense verbs of hearing have **three** distinct forms; sight has **two**, and the others **one** apiece)

- (**Non-Volitional** verb) *I **heard** the song*
  *I **saw** the painting*
  *I **tasted** the soup* (same for volitional)
  *I **smelled** the soup* (same for volitional)
  *I **felt** the fabric*  (same for volitional)
- (**Volitional** verb)   *I **listened to** the song*
  *I **looked at** the painting*
- (**Experiential** verb)  *The song **sounded** strange (to me)*
  *The soup **looked/tasted/smelled** strange (to me)*
  *The fabric **felt** strange (to me)*

So, basically, you're right. The term you're looking for is "volitional" (meaning doing something on purpose), and it contrasts with "non-volitional" (meaning doing something by accident). It's the same difference as the difference between *pour* and *spill* -- pouring is volitional while spilling is non-volitional; otherwise they're the same. There's [a lot more syntax involved with sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20%22sense%20verb%22) in English, however.

Answer (score 4):

They are [Action Verbs](http://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/action-verbs.html) versus [Stative Verbs](http://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/stative-verb.html).

Action verbs describe some effort a subject takes. In English, they are *look*, *listen*, and so on.

Stative verbs describe state which a subject is in, **regardless of** whether or not he/she makes any effort to reach that state. In English, they are *see*, *hear*, etc.

In English, [there are also verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/444/what-is-the-difference-between-look-see-and-watch) that describe continuous action, like *watch*.

As far as I know, many languages have such pairs, for example:

- Thai: ดู (look) and มอง (stare, goggle) vs. เห็น (see)
- Ukrainian: дивитися (look) vs. бачити (see)

..and so on

Sorry for a very short answer, but it actually answers the entire question.

Comment: Another way of saying more or less the same thing is that *look, listen* are volitional, while *see, hear* are non-volitional.